# To find all users in the given roles discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I wanted to make a program to find all the users in the given roles, like if
roll a has members 1, 2, 3, 4
and roll b has members 2, 3
I want the code to give outputs 2, 3

This is the main code for making a list of those users(mentions)

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Admins')
async def find(ctx,*, name):
  guild=ctx.guild
  roles=name.split(",")
  role=get(guild.roles, name=roles[0])
  members=role.members
  for role in roles[1:]:
    role = get(guild.roles, name=role.strip(" "))
    lm=role.members
    for i in members:
      if i not in lm:
        members.remove(i)

        
  l=[f"{role.mention}" for role in members]   
  print(l)
```

Can someone please help me find the error in the code? When I gave in b, an I get the output right, not so much when it a, b

Comment: Why overcomplicating the code so much? Just get the role object and use the `members` attribute. `role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID); members = role.members`

Comment: I need the list that mentions the users, basically I'm making an embedded message that displays and mentions the list of users in all the given roles

Comment: What's difficult about it? You already have a list of members and you used a bit of list comprehension in your code to get a list of mentions, pretty sure you can figure that one out by yourself  

Comment: Modified the code to this, still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using sets and intersection solves the problem, don't know how it works but it does

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Admins')
async def find(ctx,*, name):
  guild=ctx.guild
  roles=name.split(",")
  role=get(guild.roles, name=roles[0])
  members=set(role.members)
  for role in roles[1:]:
    role = get(guild.roles, name=role.strip(" "))
    lm=set(role.members)
    members=members.intersection(lm)

        
  l=[f"{role.mention}" for role in members]   
  print(l)
```